# Graphviz installation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, graphviz, dot

I am trying to create a dot file using [JDD project](http://javaddlib.sourceforge.net/jdd/). It requires installation of Graphviz. I tried to install it using console:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

In that case, although the installation seemed successful, the program did not produce me any output. Therefore I tried another approach by downloading the top most [.deb file](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php) but I got the error:

> "Dependency is not satisfiable: libgraphviz4 (>=2.18)"

Does anyone know how I can make it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me on a 64-bit machine.

Try adding these lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main 
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you should be able to install by double clicking the .deb file, or using dpkg, etc, which ever way you prefer.

NOTE: I think your first attempt might've actually worked, though. The issue is that the command installs a group of tools, none named 'graphviz'. I found this information here:

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61037-package-graphviz-installation-appears-not-to-work

**You will need to install a gui/visualization tool to open .gv files. xdot (`sudo apt install xdot`) is such a tool and can also be located on the Ubuntu software center.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also do `sudo apt-get install graphviz` after updating apt.