# How to install graphviz in Ubuntu 15 to plot a decision tree for XGBoost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I want to plot the decision tree of XGBoost. 
I followed the instructions from this [webpage](http://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/).
I get this error:

```
 ImportError: You must install graphviz to plot tree
```

I tried to install graphviz_2.38.0-1~saucy_amd64.deb from [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php).
But I get this error:

```
 *Dependency is not satisfiable:libgraphviz4(>=2.18)*
```

So I did what is on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630434/graphviz-installation-ubuntu-14-04)

As it still does not work I downloaded the source code:
graphviz-2.40.1.tar.gz  But it still does not work.
I thought that maybe I have installed it in the wrong path. So what does this mean: Make sure that the directory containing the dot executable is on your systems’ path?

I have installed it in /etc.

I use a virtual environment in conda

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I used pip install graphviz.
now I get this error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tpng']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: The original 15.xx packages are here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/graphviz/ .. You will probably need   ` `libcgraph6_2.38.0-5build1_amd64.deb` and `graphviz_2.38.0-5build1_amd64.deb` .

Comment: Thanks. I will remove what I have installed and try the packages.

Comment: All? dependencies, etc. : libcdt5, libcgraph6, libgd3, libgvc6, libgvpr2, libgraphviz-dev, libvpx3, libpathplan4 . ... One question: Why don't you install graphviz with **apt** ?

Comment: No. only graphviz_2.38.0-5build1_amd64.deb   Do you mean sudo apt-get install graphviz? I already tested that. Same problem. There is even a post in stackoverflow about it.

Answer (score 10):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation), you will need to install two conda packages:

- **graphviz**, which only installs the graphviz system binaries.
- **python-graphviz**, which installs the Python package for interfacing with graphviz.

So, install both packages with

```
conda install graphviz python-graphviz
```

and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are different packages that are called graphviz. Some of them refer to python packages others not. I think you are referring to the python version, but probably you installed the non-python version. If you refer to the python package, you can install it with pip ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433274/anaconda-graphviz-cant-import-after-installation))

```
pip install graphviz
python -c "import graphviz"
# should give no errors
```

**In addition** you need the non-python version. You also can either install it via anaconda.

```
conda install graphviz
# this installs the non-python executables
```

Or you use the `apt-get` (I did not check whether this works):

```
apt-get install graphviz
```